# C++ pointer arithmetic conversion confusion

Tags: c++

I was looking at this [algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263224/547803) and came along these lines of code

```
static const double one = 1.00000000000000000000e+00, /* 0x3FF00000, 0x00000000 */
int n0,hx,ix,i;
double R,S,P,Q,s,y,z,r;
n0 = ((*(int*)&one)>>29)^1;
hx = *(n0+(int*)&x);
```

I do not understand, in particular, what `((*(int*)&one)>>29)^1` is doing. When I put into the debugger, it always evaluates to 1. Is this an old compiler hack back in 1993 (the original code is from SUN 1993, as per the copyright notice)?

Edit: the function snippet from the link

```
double erf(double x)
{
  int n0,hx,ix,i;
  double R,S,P,Q,s,y,z,r;
  n0 = ((*(int*)&one)>>29)^1;
  hx = *(n0+(int*)&x);
  ix = hx&0x7fffffff;
  if(ix>=0x7ff00000) { /* erf(nan)=nan */
    i = ((unsigned)hx>>31)<<1;
    return (double)(1-i)+one/x; /* erf(+-inf)=+-1 */
  }

  if(ix < 0x3feb0000) { /* |x|<0.84375 */
  // ... too much to paste
```

Comment: Kind of reminds me of [fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) it is probably some way of quickly approximate some floating point operation on a machine that didn't have floating point support on its CPU. Is there a bit more context you can give? Like the name of the function it is used in or what the code as a whole should do?

Comment: It's extracting some bit from the floating point representation of `1.0`. **I think** it might be some kind of endianness test on the floating point format. Certainly the next line which extracts either the high or low 32 bits from `x` suggests that.

Comment: Context is the [erf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf) function. But that's a pretty obscure function. Numerical analysis expert required I think.

Comment: I guess there is some need to convert it to int for the conversions later, but the n0 eludes me completely.

Comment: I think the downvotes are mostly about the title of your question, it has nothing todo with C# and more with floating point "magic" ;)

Comment: @Augunrik There's no conversion going on here. The casts are on pointers not on integer or floating point values. This is called *type punning* where you treat one type as if it was another. This technique where you make a pointer, cast the pointer and then dereference is a common way to do that. In this case the code is extracting bits from the floating point representation.

Comment: Judging by the provided name, it must've been an outdated version of: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf . There is a wiki link to mathematical definition inside the URI. Those downvotes are targeting bad style. Type punning and pointer arithmetic are no more promoted; the downsides and safe alternatives have been around for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(double) 1.0 is `0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` in binary. The value consists of 64 bits.

`(int*)&one` means using the same memory address, but interpret it as a pointer to int. The size of int is only 32 bits, and by dereferencing it like `(*(int*)&one)` you get either the "first half" `00111111111100000000000000000000` or the "second half" `00000000000000000000000000000000` depending on the endian (assume that the endianness is the same for floating-point numbers as for integers)

Right-shifting by 29 bits results will extract the first 3 bits (and add 29 `0` bits), i.e. `00000000000000000000000000000001` in the first case and `00000000000000000000000000000000` in the second case.

Then `^1` (xor with 1) is used to change `(int) 1` into `(int) 0` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I've googled more around and found another, updated implementation:

https://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.txt?format=txt&filename=fdlibm%2Fs_erf.c

There the code has been updated to

```
hx = __HI(x);
```

The macro __HI(x) is defined here

```
#ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define __HI(x) *(1+(int*)&x)
#define __LO(x) *(int*)&x
#define __HIp(x) *(1+(int*)x)
#define __LOp(x) *(int*)x
#else
#define __HI(x) *(int*)&x
#define __LO(x) *(1+(int*)&x)
#define __HIp(x) *(int*)x
#define __LOp(x) *(1+(int*)x)
#endif
```

so [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) was right that it's some form of endianness extractor.